# MySQL. Way to compose query with "LIKE" which will work similar as url regular expression

Tags: mysql, sql-like

for example I have table 'urls'
urls:

```
___________________________________________
|   id   |              href              |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    1   | /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/                |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    2   | /a/b/g/                        |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    3   | /a/c/g/                        |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    4   | /a/d/g/                        |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    5   | /a.php?code=g                  |
+--------+--------------------------------|
|    N   | anyUrlString                   |
+--------+--------------------------------|
```

I wanna select urls which have special format, for example (like ROUTE in popular PHP frameworks)

```
"/a/@anyparam/g"
```

so: `WHERE href LIKE '/a/%/g'`
but it also will select row with id `5`, `1`..
How to compose `LIKE` statement to I can get only URI enabled values in @anyparam ? 
must be something like this `/a/[%, but not ('/','?','\')]/g` but what exactly?
Thanks for any proposition!
P.S. Do not propose to use regular expression (it don't use indexes)!

Comment: Use `REGEXP` operator

Comment: @Page, this will not use indexes, right? so I will loose performance in large tables... yes?

Comment: You cannot use indexes on such a query anyway, so using regular expressions seems unavoidable.

Comment: If you don't want to use regular expressions, you can only use `like ... and not like ... `. Define the appropriate patterns to include / exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use multiple clauses?

```
 LIKE '/a/%/g' AND NOT LIKE '/a/%?%/g' ....
```

Chain some "exceptions" together, attacking cases that do not match.  It's hard to come up with a general case, with your limited sample set.  An `EXPLAIN` will show if Indexes are still in use.

Comment: Ha-ha!!! Thanks!!! Really great solution.. In a same way as CSS selector trick "have attribute and attribute is not empty" ( [Data-Attribute]:not([Data-Attribute=""] )
Cool!! Thanks again! @mainstreet

Answer (score 0):

String and pattern taken from your code:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '/a.php?code=g' LIKE '/a/%/g'
```

^ should not give you anything, since the string your testing doesn't end in `/g`, it ends with `=g`.

But an often overlooked ability of `LIKE` is negative character-classes. Unfortunately they are not variable-length, they always only represent 1 character, but you could `REPEAT()` them:

```
LIKE '/a/' + REPEAT('[^/?\]', LEN(@someVar)) + '/g'
```